# Is it correct if I say that all Java objects are polymorphic?

Tags: java, object, polymorphism

Since all Java classes inherits from the super-class **Object**, can we conclude that all Java objects are polymorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is absolutely correct.  
As stated in [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm)

> In Java, all Java objects are polymorphic since any object will pass
> the IS-A test for their own type and for the class Object.

Also in the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has
> Object as a superclass

Thus every object has attributes from `Object` class like `public String toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

No. objects created from class `java.lang.Object` which is the root of the class hierarchy are not polymorphic. They are instances of `java.lang.Object` class only.